# Why I'm unable to access the outer class variable from inner class?

Tags: java

I'm doing something like below but it's not working. Why is that? And how to do it?

```
public class A {
    private int a;

    private class BInner {
        a = 10;
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you try to make a statement outside a method. Try this in a method of the inner class and it should work.

Comment: So what's the solution?

Comment: Adding a method? See the answer.

Comment: "not working" is not a problem description.

Comment: To access `a`, try `A.this.a = 10`.

Answer (score 2):

Usually the initialization stuff is done inside a constructor, so you can change or init the `outer class` variable `a` inside the constructor of `inner class`; like this:

```
public class A {
    private int a;

    private class BInner {
        public BInner(){
           a = 10;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to do the statement in a method:

```
public class A {
    private int a;

    private class BInner {
        void changeA(){
           a = 10;
        }
    }
}
```